# NIFI Iterate on date

Tags: loops, iterator, apache-nifi

I'm working on Nifi Flow and my problem is:

I need to discover the first day of actual month like in oracle function for example.

My job will run though a loop that in each iterate he will pass a date on atribute and this date will be usable on the query each time until actual today.

I can use nifi function to recover the today's day, but, how can i discover the first day of month based of the today's date using nifi functions, without  use milleseconds minus function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following expression will format date in Y-M-D format but instead of day there will be literal `01`

```
${now():format("yyyy-MM-'01'")}
```

Comment: Ye bro, it works as my first day of month.
Many thanks!